# Unidentified branch on remote repository

Tags: git

There is an extra branch `my-app/master` in my remote repository and I don't know how it got there. Doing a git fetch doesn't add the branch to my local repository. Can I find out how it got there and get rid of it?

```
> git branch -r
   my-app/master
   origin/HEAD -> origin/master
   origin/master
   origin/release-0.1
   origin/feature-a
```

local: git branch

```
  master
* release-0.1
  feature-a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my-app/master` isn't a branch. It's a combination of remote repository and branch.
Besides the default remote repository, you have a remote repository with alias `my-app` which has a branch with the name `master`.

(`origin` is usually the alias for the default remote repository.)

You can see where they point to with:

```
git remote -v
```

(However, there is no command which allows you to find out how it got there. If it was added via the terminal/command-line you could look in the terminal/command-line history.)

You can delete a alias for a remote repository with:

```
git remote remove <name>
```